# Given $T:E^*\to E^*,$ does there exist $S:E\to E$ such that $\langle Te^*,e \rangle = \langle e^*,Se\rangle?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $T:E\to E$ be a bounded linear operator.
Denote $E^*$ a dual space of $E,$ that is, the space of all bounded linear functional $e^*:E\to\mathbb{R}.$

It is well known that if $T:E\to E$ is a bounded linear operator, then there exists a bounded linear operator $T^*:E^*\to E^*$ such that for all $e^*\in E^*$ and $e\in E,$
$$\langle Te^*,e \rangle = \langle e^*,Se\rangle.$$
In most literature, $T^*$ is called **adjoint operator** of $T.$

I would like to know its converse, that is,

> **Question:** Given a bounded linear operator $T:E^*\to E^*,$ does there exist bounded linear operator $S:E\to E$ such that for all $e\in E$ and $e^*\in E^*,$
>   $$\langle Te^*,e \rangle = \langle e^*,Se\rangle?$$

If $T:E^*\to E^*$ is assumed to be weak$^*$-to-weak$^*$ continuous, then the question has positive answer.

What happens if we remove weak$^*$-to-weak$^*$ continuity?
Is the answer still positive?

Comment: In the sentence just below the boxed text, when you state "If $T:E^*\to E^*$ is assumed...", do you mean $T:E^*\to E^*$?  Talking about the weak$^*$ topology on $E$ doesn't always make sense.

Comment: @Aweygan: Yes, you are right. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily prove the reverse of the sentence after your question: If an $S$ as in the question exists, then $T$ is weak*-weak* continuous.

Comment: I see. So the question has negative answer in general.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T\in L(X,Y)$ (linear and bounded, $X,Y$ normed spaces). We can show that $$T^{**}\circ J_{X}=J_{Y}\circ T,$$
with $J_X$ the natural embedding from $X$ to $X^{**}$ via $(J_X x)(x^*)=x^*(x)$.

Back to your case: If $E$ is reflexive, then $S=J_{E}^{-1}\circ T^*\circ J_{E}$. With this you have that $T=S^*$ and so $$\langle Te^*,e\rangle=\langle S^*e^*,e\rangle=\langle e^*,Se\rangle.$$